# Log4j filter marker data

Tags: java, log4j2

I use marker for inbound and outbound packets. All packets prefixed by int id. Sometimes for debug purpopses i need also filter packets by id. How i can for example log packets prefixed with 3?

```
private static final Marker packets = MarkerManager.getMarker("Packets");

logger.debug(packets, "[IN:" + packetState + ":" + packet.getId() + "] " + packet.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegexFilter to do this: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter

Answer (score 0):

you could use apache ThreadContext to put the id there and then retrieve the map in you log via the convention Id:[%X{id}]  where id is the id you put in the ThreadContext Map ..